# Windows 10 Boot Grub Boot Error (unknown filesystem)

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

First off, I did my research and I dug around and I could not find this solution anywhere.

I recently installed Linux as a dual boot onto my HP Omen Laptop, after the installation, I restarted and I now have a grub error

```
error: no such device: 6181e04c-0931-47cf-a5a1-531d37e9662
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub
```

When trying `ls`, I get: `(hd0), (hd0,gpt4), (hd0,gpt3), (hd0,gpt2), (hd0,gpt1)`
When typing each `ls` `(hd0)`, `(hd0,gpt4)`, `(hd0,gpt3)`, `(hd0,gpt2)` and `(hd0,gpt1)` I get `Filesystem is Unknown` for all of them

I would like to keep my data, but I do have everything backed up, only issue is the Windows key, the computer came pre-installed with Windows and I didn't think to write down the Windows key somewhere.

Comment: windows has your key, it will verify automatically

Comment: Is secure boot on? it may be preventing grub from loading modules. or possible you installed ubuntu in legacy mode

Comment: as of now, i cant access anything other than the rescue mode, when i boot up my computer, i dont even have a loading screen, i just go straight to rescue mode

Comment: if you installed in Legacy mode, Legacy boot can not read GPT partitions. and since grubs config file is on the partitions ...

Comment: how do you suggest i go about solving this issue then?

Comment: Open firmware settings by holding the correct function key while booting. disable legacy/CSM support to ensure EFI boot and reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: thats exactly the issue here, i dont know which button to press, there isnt even an dell type logo, it goes straight to the grub rescue within half a second

Comment: it is fast. hold while turning on. my hp uses F10, but could be any

Comment: this is odd, legacy support is already disabled...